# New 2.5" SSD won't fit - my MacBook pro says it's a mid 2012 15" model

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

So I just paid £200 for a new SSD hard drive (Crucial said it was a suitable upgrade for my MacBook Pro 15" mid 2012).

But this isn't what I was expecting to see. :(

What am I looking at? Why didn't it look like the [iFixit guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Hard+Drive+Replacement/10761)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That definitely looks like a Mid-2012 MacBook Pro **Retina**.

From [iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Pro_15%22_Retina_Display_Mid_2012):

[image]

Comment: Yeah that looks like it. Thanks Allen. Drives for these things are much harder to replace and cost twice as much :(

Comment: Yes, - however, I am trying to find a link to somewhere that indicated an "adapter" was available to use the "regular" M2 SSDs and that High Sierra was compatible with it.  If/when I find it, I will edit my answer so you have a path to go down to upgrade this MBP.

Comment: See this [relevant post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287644/do-macbooks-support-nvme-ssd-drives-via-the-use-of-a-sintech-adapter) on compatible NVM drives.   They should work in the 2013 MBP

Comment: Mid-2012 and early 2013 15” retina MacBook Pro did not have NVMe storage. They were SATA SSDs over a proprietary connector.