# As High Sierra does now support 512 byte block sizes, are Samsung 960 NVMe SSD fit in a Macbook pro retina 15 mid-2015 with a Sintech adapter?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd

I know that there is already some topics on this forum about that but I didn't find a clear answer or if someone have tested it since then.

[Do MacBooks support NVMe SSD drives via the use of a Sintech adapter?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287644/do-macbooks-support-nvme-ssd-drives-via-the-use-of-a-sintech-adapter)

Comment: It's really frustrating that the answer you link to is closed even though there are two answers that totally disagree with each other.

Someone presumably must have tested this by now??