# NVMe Drives for Macbook Pro's

Tags: macbook-pro

I have been following this thread(Forgive me, I am new here and do not know how to reply to the existing thread):

[Do MacBooks support NVMe SSD drives via the use of a Sintech adapter?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287644/do-macbooks-support-nvme-ssd-drives-via-the-use-of-a-sintech-adapter)

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012) 2.6Ghz Intel Core i7, 16GB DDR3 with the GeForce GT 650M 1GB and it has the Apple SSD SM512E.

I am running macOS High Sierra 10.13.3 and I want to put a Samsung EVO 960 NVMe 2TB in it. Can I do that. All the data in the thread I linked to is 2013 Macbooks or newer.

Comment: Should older hardware somehow get drivers or the ability to run, let's update the comprehensive post rather than asking questions about each possible older Mac that the linked question states quite clearly don't work.

Answer (score 1):

No - you need a newer Mac to take advantage of the new storage connections and protocols.

This is well covered in the exhaustive post on what hardware has drivers and connections needed for NVMe to operate:

- [Do MacBooks support NVMe SSD drives via the use of a Sintech adapter?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287644/do-macbooks-support-nvme-ssd-drives-via-the-use-of-a-sintech-adapter)

Comment: I appologize, Apparently I do not have enough "Reputation" points to comment or reply to the post that I linked to. That prevents me from communicating on that post. If I had the required reputation points I would go ahead and use that thread.

I did re-read that post and again, Specific comments on that post only refer to 2013 Macbook Pro models and newer machines.

Since NVMe drives are not compatible with the machine I have, which drives are compatible?

Comment: Agreed - that's why I put an answer here to explain before linking as duplicate.

Comment: So I got my pentalobe p5 screw driver today and and popped the cover and then pulled the SSD out of the Macbook Pro. It is a Samsung MZ-DPC512A/0A2. Googling that, I found that it is an mSATA SSD. The Samsung EVO 960's just came out in an mSATA form factor. They should be backwards compatible (at least on the PC side) so I am going to order one and an adapter to see if I can get a 1TB EVO 960 mSATA to work in this PC that runs macOS with an Apple logo on it.

Comment: Woah @Snowleopard -  Cool update. Please add an answer no matter if this works or not. I’d love to be proved wrong and you document this.

Comment: The comprehensive answer is quite messy to sift through, highest voted answer is from user that seems absent now, and it doesn't answer my Qs as well: Is BootRom the EFI-Update that comes with HS (will Sierra work once that is applied?), does it really require APFS (awful, want to downgrade to HFS), will the combo *I set my eyes on* (not listed) work? Are all those then likely dupes?